# Pig UDF Throwing NullPointerException When Generating New Tuple

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-pig, udf, pig-udf

I have a Pig UDF which ingests some data and then attempts to transform that data in a minimal manner.

```
my_data = LOAD 'path/to/data' USING SomeCustomLoader();
my_other_data = FOREACH my_data GENERATE MyUDF(COL_1, COL_2, $param1, $param2) as output;
my_final_data = FOREACH my_other_data GENERATE output.NEW_COL1, output.NEW_COL2, output.NEW_COL3;
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

> ERROR 0: Exception while executing [POUserFunc (Name: POUserFUnc(udf.MyUDF)[tuple] - scope-38 Operator Key: scope-38) children: null at []]: java.lang.NullPointerException

My UDF takes the data and transforms it:

```
public class MyUDF extends EvalFunc<Tuple> {
    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;

        TupleFactory _factory;

        Long fieldOne;
        String fieldTwo;
        String fieldThree;

        _factory.getInstance();

        try {
            fieldOne = Long.valueOf(input.get(0).toString());
            fieldTwo = input.get(1).toString();
            fieldThree = input.get(2).toString();

            fieldOne = doSomething(fieldOne);
            fieldTwo = doSomething(fieldTwo);
            fieldThree = doSomething(fieldThree);

            return _factory.newTuple(Arrays.asList(fieldOne, fieldTwo, fieldThree));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return _factory.newTuple(Arrays.asList("ParseException", "", "", ""));
        }
    }
}
```

I have debugged and confirmed that fieldOne, fieldTwo, and fieldThree *do exist* prior to calling the tuple factory. It's also clear that the exception is being thrown because the code reaches the `catch` block and then throws this `NullPointerException` error.

What is not clear is why on earth this is happening.

According to the Pig docs (Pig 0.14.0 API), I should be able to call `newTuple(java.util.List c)` with the relevant items.

I have also defined my own Schema to ensure the types are correct when going back to the pig script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in question has not instantiated your tuple instance, thus you cannot call the method on an object that does not exist.

```
public class ... {
    TupleFactory _factory;
    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) {
        _factory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
        ...
    }
}
```